# How to get the Android developer classes (packages) in my AS3 project

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, package

I'm a 20 year old Android developer, and i'm having some trouble publishing my application. The thing is that I want my application to work on every device screen. To do so I figured out I need to use the DIP class (`DPI independent pixels`) of the android packages.

The problem is I can't find them anywhere. I have looked for weeks new and it's driving me absolutely nuts. The one who can help me solve this problem I will pay good.

Comment: You're talking about using the android SDK through actionscript? I didn't know actionscript and java were inter-operable.

Comment: @Jon: I suspect that he is developing a flash or Air application for Android.

Comment: Yes I am making an AIR application, and that's the problem. I cant get the classes in Flash CS5 or Flashdevelop.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to test for pixel density: Ie. Something like this

```
if(Capabilities.screenDPI <= 160){
// do this
}
else if (Capabilities.screenDPI > 160 && Capabilities.screenDPI <= 240){
// do something else
}
else{
// do this for retina screens
}
```

You could make the `screenDPI` a constant, which may help a tiny little bit with performance as you would only need to check once.